# Target DIV inside table with hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs

have a regular table, which looks like this.

```
 <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <div class="img"></div>
               </td>
           <tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

In my div with the class "img" I have a background-image: url('') with grayscale 100%.

I want to be able to remove the grayscale, when I hover over this `<td>`. Is this possible? I'm not exactly sure how to "target" the div and remove it.

I have made something like this:

```
.img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%)
}
```

But it doesn't work since it's the td thats getting a hovered, not the actual div.

I also tried to put a absolute div, inside a relative div in my td. Then I can target it, but it will only work when I hover on the div, not the `<td>`.

Is this possible? I am using React, so if it's easier with JS I guess that could be one solution.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators

Answer (score 1):

As Quentin suggested you can do it easily via CSS descendant selectors. Put the hover on the TD, and apply the filter only when the TD is not hovered:

```css
.img {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  background: url(https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_3439cf77256d_96.png);  
}

td:not(:hover) > .img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);  
}
```

```html
 <table>
      <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <div class="img"></div>
               </td>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i played with your code a little and I think the only thing you were missing was the semi-colon. Have a look

https://jsfiddle.net/max234435/s00fzn7g/

I have added `background-color: red;` because I can't really grey scale nothing. Hope that helps.